# Error on Zone not having enough resource available! but selecting all other zones will lead to this error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, resources, vertex, workbench

When I want to create user-managed notebook in vertex's workbench, every zone that i would select, there would be this error:

*tensorflow-2-6-20230629-002759: The zone 'projects/qwiklabs-gcp-04-478447ba3eee/zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.: Something went wrong. Sorry about that.
*
it's been two days, that i get this error again and again.

anyone can help on what is causing this?

I changed the zone, changed the notebook type, tensor version, and every details on notebook creating dialoug box. but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received:

```
The zone 'projects/qwiklabs-gcp-04-478447ba3eee/zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

typically indicates that the Compute Engine resource you requested is currently unavailable in a zone and cannot accommodate your request due to unavailability. This is a [common resource error](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability) and can happen for various reasons such as high demand, regional limitations and to prevent unforeseen spikes in usage.

Here's a few steps you can take when encountering this error:

1. Retry your request at a different zone and a different time
2. Check [Regional availability](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones)
3. Modify your resource or configuration, if possible choose other options that are more readily available
4. [Create reservations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview) for your Compute Engine resources
5. If none of these steps resolve the issue, I suggest contacting [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/contact) to help you find the proper solution.